# Bash file test conditionals

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I'm generating panoramas using the command line versions of the Hugin toolset.  At the execution of the script, all images are sorted into folders of n images that consist of a single panorama.  Depending on the execution of the blend process, one of two filenames can result: `pano.tif` and `pano_blended_fused.tif`.

No matter which file is generated, I want to convert that one to a jpg and resize.  My current code is

```
dirlist=$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name completed \) | sort -n)
for dir in $dirlist
do
    #pano generating gode goes here


  #Downsize and convert panorama
  #######################################################################
  tifImage=
  jpgImage=

  if [ -e "pano.tif" ]; then
    tifImage="pano.tif"
    jpgImage="pano.jpg"
    echo "Working on pano.tif"
    echo ""

  elif [ -e "pano_blended_fused" ]; then
    tifImage="pano_blended_fused.tif"
    jpgImage="pano_blended_fused.jpg"
    echo "Working on pano_blended_fused.tif"
    echo ""
  fi

  #convert pano to jpg and get count of images in photo folder
  echo ""
  echo "Converting $image to jpg and creating two versions"
  echo ""
  mogrify -format jpg $tifImage >> "$imagePath/$dir/log.txt"

  num=$(ls -l "$webPath/photos" | wc -l) 
  prefix=$((num+1))

  #convert full size pano to 1000 pixels high and rename with prefix number
  #move to /photos folder
  convert $jpgImage -geometry x1000 "$prefix-pano.jpg" >> "$imagePath/$dir/log.txt"
  mv "$prefix-pano.jpg" "$webPath/photos" >> "$imagePath/$dir/log.txt"

  #convert full size pano to 600 pixels wide and rename with prefix number
  #move to /thumbs folder
  convert $jpgImage -geometry 600x "$prefix-pano.jpg" >> "$imagePath/$dir/log.txt"
  mv "$prefix-pano.jpg" "$webPath/thumbs"  >> "$imagePath/$dir/log.txt"


done
```

I just did a batch of pictures last night, and of the 15 panoramas to be generated, only 9 made it to the destiniation folder.  All others threw an error at the first `convert` command stating that it was missing an image filename `n-pano.tif`, when the `$tifImage` varuiable should have been `pano_blended_fused.tif`

What do I need to do so that the `pano_blended_fused` images can go through the conversion process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the complete filename, the extension is missing:

```
elif [ -e "pano_blended_fused" ]; then
```

vs.

```
elif [ -e "pano_blended_fused.tif" ]; then
```

Therefore the variables were never changed and `convert` didn't get what it wanted.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that stupid mistake.  Guess I was a lil tired to miss a rookie error.